# Camel File move to directory instead of file

Tags: apache-camel

I have a file route such as:

```
    from("file://" + inbox + "" +
            "?delay=1000" +
            "&preMove=/tmp/staging" +
            "&move=/tmp/processed")
            .bean(MyProcessor.class)
            .marshal(listJacksonDataFormat)
            .to("restlet:http://localhost:58080/new-greeting?restletMethod=POST");
```

Given file in inbox is: `mycalc.xls`

For some reason after the route has processed camel moves `mycalc.xls` to a **file** named `/tmp/processed` instead of moving it to the  `/tmp/processed/` **directory** and preserve the original file name of `mycalc.xls`.

**EDIT:**

Here is my simplified MyProcessor class:

```
@Component
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {

  @Override
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
    log.info("Processing file: " + file);

    exchange.getOut().setBody("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Ok, I have found the problem line which is:

`exchange.getOut().setBody("Hello World");`

As soon as that call is made, I get the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Seems that the problem is related to the marshal operation. If I don't do the marshal operation it works as expected.

Comment: Not sure I understand, you mean the content of mycalc.xls is moved to a file named processed under tmp folder?

Comment: what Camel version and OS are you using?

Comment: Clause: I tried with both camel 2.15.3 and camel 2.16.1. Same behavior in both. On Linux.

Comment: Souciance: Yup. It behaves exactly the same as if the command mv /tmp/inbox/mycalc.xls /tmp/processed was executed

Comment: try without preMove, or `&move=/tmp/processed/${file:name}`

Comment: and it can also be your custom processor that do not close an input stream or something that causes a _lock_ on the file or something

Comment: Claus: I tried preMove and &move, no luck. I have pasted my custom processor in my original post for you to have a look at. I have simplified what I really do with it but the behaviour is still the same. I am sure it is something really obvious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to change: `exchange.getOut().setBody("Hello World");` to `exchange.getIn().setBody("Hello World");`

From what I gather I was incorrectly using the In-Out (Request/Reply) Message Exchange pattern by explicitly replying on the File exchange.

Reasons as to why this wasn't the right thing to do are:

a.) it wasn't necessary to do in the first place as Camel does pass the message along the Exchanges by default and

b.) by using `getOut()` a new message was created that was then set as the IN on the following Exchange that then resulted in the problem.

For more info, please see: http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Claus - "move" and "preMove" options in general expecting target filename expression and not just directory name (but it works with dir names like ".done"). So first try to change your route to:

```
from("file://" + inbox + "" +
        "?delay=1000" +
        "&preMove=/tmp/staging/${file:name}" +
        "&move=/tmp/processed/${file:name}")
        .bean(MyProcessor.class)
        .marshal(listJacksonDataFormat)
        .to("restlet:http://localhost:58080/new-greeting?restletMethod=POST");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't make a difference